# Javascript Canvas library optimized for mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, canvas

I'm looking for a fast canvas library optimized for mobile browsers. I have tried KinectJS and Fabric.js, but they are both slow or have too many bugs (artifacts, untriggered events, etc.) when using Phonegap.

Does anyone recommend a nice library with similar functionality?

Comment: I'd strongly consider making a native app. The whole "desktop-like apps in browsers" thing only works because of the obscene amounts of resources available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking for libraries is kind of off topic here, but these are the popular ones (this list came from [MDN - Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas) )

[Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) is an open source vector graphics scripting framework that runs on top of the HTML5 Canvas

[libCanvas](http://libcanvas.github.com/) is powerful and lightweight canvas framework

[Processing.js](http://processingjs.org) is a port of the Processing visualization language

[EaselJS](http://easeljs.com/) is a library with a Flash-like API

[PlotKit](http://www.liquidx.net/plotkit/) is a charting and graphing library

[Rekapi](https://github.com/jeremyckahn/rekapi) is an animation keyframing API for Canvas

[PhiloGL](http://senchalabs.github.com/philogl/) is a WebGL framework for data visualization, creative coding and game development.

[JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/) creates interactive 2D Canvas data visualizations for the Web.

[Frame-Engine](http://www.frame-engine.com) is a framework for developing applications and games

Comment: Related: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aqj_mVmuz3Y8dHNhUVFDYlRaaXlyX0xYSTVnalV5ZlE#gid=0